# Diificulty in using Events and Delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, delegates

I was trying to call a method which is in the parent page from a user control :

user control:

```
    public delegate void CallParent();
    public event CallParent BindData;

   protected void LoadDataPageWise(int iCurrentPage)
        {
            iPageIndex1 = iCurrentPage - 1;
            BindData();           // This should trigger method in parent page
            DisplayPageNumber();
        }
```

Parent Page:

How to attach that delegate in the page load of Parent Page?

```
   public void BindGridRecords()
        {
            grdPages.PageIndex = rptPager.iPageIndex1;
            grdPages.DataBind();
            Session["PageIndex"] = grdPages.PageIndex;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your parent page's load method:

`rptPager.BindData += this.BindGridRecords;`

Comment: Assuming `grdPages` is the User Control's name.  If not, put the User Control's name there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `this.Page` on the control. You can cast that property to your actual page object and then call any method you want on that object as long as it is accessible.